# nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request " in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:24

Tags: nginx, centos, unicorn

Out error I tried start nginx in the following environment, did not go well.

```
#env
CentOS v6.5
nginx v1.6.1
unicorn v4.8.3

#error message
nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request " in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:24
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

#nginx.conf
http {

omit code

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent"';

omit code...
}
```

added code in nginx.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set up log_format before access_log, not with one directive.

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent"';

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
```

[nginx docs for log settings](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)

Comment: thanks...Are doing it already, but why subject error occurs.
added file nginx.conf

Comment: thanks
Error of a little while ago is no longer out.
Instead it is now out with ": [emerg] no path in the unix domain socket in upstream" unix:: "in / etc / nginx / sites-enabled / admin nginx 2", but listen and the unicorn, and upstream unix of will not describe the same path.